# Jquery product display in <div> tag

Tags: jquery

My requirement left side some product name link will be there if I click product1 right box I get full desc about that product. Here I used jQuery and html5.

```
<div class="cn_wrapper">            
    <div id="cn_preview" class="cn_preview">    
    <div class="cn_content" style="top:5px;">
                content1 desc
        </div>                  
    </div>      

    <div id="cn_list" class="cn_list">
        <div class="cn_page" style="display:block;">
            <div class="cn_item selected">
                <center style="vertical-align:middle"><h2 >Content 1</h2></center>
            </div>
            <div class="cn_item selected">
                <center style="vertical-align:middle"><h2 >Content 2</h2></center>
            </div>
                .
                upto 4          
        </div>

        <div class="cn_page">
            <div class="cn_item selected">
                <center style="vertical-align:middle"><h2 >Content 5</h2></center>
            </div>
            <div class="cn_item selected">
                <center style="vertical-align:middle"><h2 >Content 6</h2></center>
            </div>
            <div class="cn_item selected">
                <center style="vertical-align:middle"><h2 >Content 7</h2></center>
            </div>
            <div class="cn_item selected">
                <center style="vertical-align:middle"><h2 >Content 8</h2></center>
            </div>
        </div>
```

here `div class="cn_page"` will display 4 product first if I click the next button then the next 4 product will display. Here I get all product list all will display at time. I used this jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "AdvService.asmx/GetDetails",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    var cars = response;

    $('#cn_list').empty();


    $.each(cars, function(index, MyData) {     

   $('#cn_list').append('<div class=cn_item selected><center style=vertical-align:middle><h2></h2>'+ MyData.Productname + '</center></div><div class="cn_nav">'+
                            '<a id="cn_prev" class="cn_prev disabled"></a>'+
                            '<a id="cn_next" class="cn_next"></a>'+
                            '</div>');

    });

  },

  failure: function(msg) {
    $('#cn_list').text(msg);
  }
});
```

Please give me an idea of how to I can show the first 4 product `div`s and when I click for the next 4 products if I click on the previous button, it should show previous 4 products.

Comment: you can add page number for your products and navigate just by increasing or decreasing page number

Answer (score 0):

If i was you.

When you append, i will use a counter to take the first 4 in a div with and id page-1 the other 4 in the second div with page-2 and all that...

And then control the style to display the page what you want.

I can't test it but i think it can work

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "AdvService.asmx/GetDetails",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    var cars = response;

    $('#cn_list').empty();

    var i = 1;
    $.each(cars, function(index, MyData) {

     if (i%10 == 0) {
        $('#cn_list').append('<div class=page></div>');
     }

   $('#cn_list .page:last').append('<div class=cn_item selected><center style=vertical-align:middle><h2></h2>'+ MyData.Productname + '</center></div><div class="cn_nav">'+
                            '<a id="cn_prev" class="cn_prev disabled"></a>'+
                            '<a id="cn_next" class="cn_next"></a>'+
                            '</div>');

    i++;
    });

  },

  failure: function(msg) {
    $('#cn_list').text(msg);
  }
});
```

Now you just need to control the css.

Comment: i am new to jquery please give idea how to use counter when append

Comment: thanks nax ..what is if (i%10 == 0) why we using this and if i put $('#cn_list .page:last').append(...  like this display will blank.

Comment: i get like this                                                  <div class="cn_page" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="cn_item">
<div class="cn_item">
<div class="cn_item">
<div class="cn_item">
<div class="cn_page" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="cn_item"> but i need        <div class="cn_page" style="display: block;">   div class="cn_item"> div class="cn_item"> div class="cn_item"> div class="cn_item"></div>

Comment: well as i say i dont tested it. The i%10 is the mod operations. means if he divide i/10 and take the rest. (ex: 7%10 r=1). So every 10 it gonna creat a page.  hmm i'm viewin it now and i think the i needs to start on 0 to creat the first page. but not sure. if i had some time tomorrow i review it

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "AdvService.asmx/GetDetails", type: "Post", dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (datas) {
        $('#cn_list').empty();

        $.each(datas, function (i, data) {

            if (((i + 1) % 4) == 0) {
                $('#cn_list').append('<div class="cn_page"></div>');
            }

            $('#cn_list .cn_page:last').append('<div class="cn_item selected"><center style="vertical-align:middle"><h2 >' + data.Content + '</h2></center></div>');

            i++;
        });
    },
    failure: function (msg) {
        $('#cn_list').text(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Still i get all product list with in the div.:-(

Comment: i get like this                                                  <div class="cn_page" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="cn_item">
<div class="cn_item">
<div class="cn_item">
<div class="cn_item">
<div class="cn_page" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="cn_item"> but i need        <div class="cn_page" style="display: block;">   div class="cn_item"> div class="cn_item"> div class="cn_item"> div class="cn_item"></div>