# jQuery inner div tag binding dynamically

Tags: jquery

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "AdvService.asmx/GetDetails",
       data: "{}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
           var cars = response;
           $('#cn_list').empty();
           var i = 1;
           $.each(cars, function (index, MyData) {
               if (i % 10 == 0) {
                   $('#cn_list').append('<div class=cn_page></div>');
               }
               $('#cn_list .cn_page:last').append('<div class=cn_item selected><center style=vertical-align:middle><h2></h2>' + MyData.Productname + '</center></div><div class="cn_nav">' + '<a id="cn_prev" class="cn_prev disabled"></a>' + '<a id="cn_next" class="cn_next"></a>' + '</div>');
               i++;
           });
       },
       failure: function (msg) {
           $('#cn_list').text(msg);
       }
   });
```

It will return `<div>` and close `</div>`, but I need `<div>` and jQuery loop content then close the `<div>` tag, how to do this?

Sorry for confusion

see my before 
[Jquery product display in <div> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376357/jquery-product-display-in-div-tag)

I get the result 100 result one by one so i manage that using below part

```
            $('#cn_list').append('<div class="cn_page"></div>')
```

what i can see in firefox respons. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4nuF.png

It should be

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ENNr.png

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Nice piece of code. Well... as there's no question here, might as well  go home now...

Comment: What's the issue here?  What do you mean by `<div> and jQuery loop content then close the <div>`?

Comment: You can try building a string w/ your HTML and then appending that string.  That way you can put the opening `<div>` and closing `<div>` where you want.

Comment: It will return

<div> class="cn_page" style="display: block;"</div>
<div> class="cn_item"</div>

<div> class="cn_page" style="display: block;"</div>
<div> class="cn_item"</div>
<div> class="cn_page" style="display: block;"</div>
But my need
<div> class="cn_page" style="display: block;"</div>
<div> class="cn_item"</div>
/<div>
<div> class="cn_page" style="display: block;"</div>
<div> class="cn_item"</div>
<div> class="cn_item"</div>
</div>
<div> class="cn_page" style="display: block;"<div> </div>
<div> class="cn_item"</div>
<div> class="cn_item"</div>
</div>

Comment: @lakshman And?  Is that wrong?  What should it return?  P.S. Add the HTML to the question not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery only appends full DOM elements.  You need to build your HTML as a string, and then append it to the DOM.

Try something like this (untested):

```
   success: function (response) {
       var cars = response, i = 1, HTML = '';
       $.each(cars, function (index, MyData) {
           if (i % 10 == 0) {
               HTML += '<div class=cn_page>';
           }
           HTML += '<div class=cn_item selected><center style=vertical-align:middle><h2></h2>' + MyData.Productname + '</center></div><div class="cn_nav">' + '<a id="cn_prev" class="cn_prev disabled"></a>' + '<a id="cn_next" class="cn_next"></a>' + '</div>';
           if (i % 10 == 0) {
               HTML += '</div>';
           }
           i++;
       });
       $('#cn_list').html(HTML);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks rocket i changed    if (v == 0){
                    HTML += '<div class="cn_page">';
           }
          
           HTML+='<div class="cn_item"><center style="vertical-align:middle"><h2>'+ MyData.clientname + '</h2></center></div>'
           alert(i);
           v=i % 4;         
         
           if (v+1 == 3){
           // if (((i + 1) % 4) == 1) {
               HTML += '</div><div class="cn_nav"><a id="cn_prev" class="cn_prev disabled"></a><a id="cn_next" class="cn_next"></a></div>';
           }
           i++;

Comment: Thanks rocket i changed     if (v == 4) (html+='</div>';                                      here for example i have 9 record it will return 4 reocord first second 4 record finall i have only 1 record if it return 4 then only </div> part will work i need find record count if record count is final one i close the div..please give me idea how to find last record